# Sharepoint 2010 Visual WebPart and LinqDataSource

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

How do I use Linq DataSource in a SharePoint 2010 Visual Web-part. When I type `<asp:LinqDataSource` there are nothing in the Visual Studio auto-complete. When I run the code I would get this error Unknown server tag 'asp:Linq DataSource'

Thanks for your help.

Comment: <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %> , this assembly is already referenced in the .ascx file.